# Transaction cannot found when using debug.traceTransaction

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, transaction-trace

I am trying to use the `debug.traceTransaction` API but got the following error:

```
>debug.traceTransaction("0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77")

Error: transaction 3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77 not found
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

This transaction seems legit via the `etherscan.io`, and I am also syncing with the main network with the following command:

```
geth --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug" console
```

Currently the progress is:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 694850,
  highestBlock: 6788672,
  knownStates: 906699,
  pulledStates: 890731,
  startingBlock: 571445
}
```

Is it because on my local machine I haven't "synced" that block? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because on my local machine I haven't "synced" that block? Thanks.

Yes. It looks like you've synced up to block `694850`, but the transaction you're looking for occurs in block `2469395`. You'll have to wait until you've caught up to at least that block number.

Comment: Aha, I see the logic here. I was expecting the API can somehow extract the trace info via network.. But seems that it will be stored locally first.

Comment: But the problem is that even if I have pulled the node (I even add a new option `--syncmode full`), I always get error msg as : `Error: required historical state unavailable`.

Comment: Although the msg can be acquired via the web interface: https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x0f503c39ba6ad304af01d05baab7c0cd557a24022ca200e09e1c936543874ef3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pulled the node." But you should be able to get the trace from your local geth node once it's been synchronized there. You might instead just want to connect to an existing public node (like Infura) and get it from them?

Comment: What I mean is that once I have synced that "block", I should be able to get traces of each transaction within that block. But it still doesn't work and show the error msg as `Error: required historical state unavailable`.